# Is it possible to fire an event in div scroll in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, scroll, angularjs-directive

How to trigger a div scroll event (not $document and $window) in Angularjs?

```
angular.element('div.myClassname').bind("scroll", function() {

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know what you wrote there will work as long as `div.myClassname` has `overflow: scroll;` and its contents are bigger then its size. Though you have to use `document.querySelector` to query. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xzt5rp2/) Though I must agree with Pankaj Parkar there that creating a directive is much more preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could do, but it should be implemented through the directive. Directive will give you the control over that DOM element, should `restrict" 'C'` which will work for `class`

**Markup**

```
<div class="myClassname">
   ..Content here to scroll..
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myClassname', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function(scope,element, attrs){
       element.bind('scroll', function(){
         //do code here
       })
    }
  }
})
```